# onClickListener only working for the last element

Tags: android, android-view

In my onCreate, I insert every buttons of my Activity in a ArrayList and I loop on them to bind a clickListener. Only the last element gets the bind. Why is that?

```
for(Button bouton: tousLesBoutons) {
        bouton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                resultat.setText(((Button) v).getText());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Actually no, only 2 of the 10 buttons gets the bind...

Comment: Does the bouton need to be initialized as a final?

Comment: The button is V and is a parameter.

I honestly can't see. But you could just try logging out put on the button click first, just to verify.

It could still be your container blocking the touch event.

Comment: Can you show the onCreate too?

Comment: @Maxwell The error in your code doesn't appear to be in the code you've pasted. It's probably elsewhere in your program, most likely the way you're initializing the array. Try stepping through your code in a debugger, rather than trying to guess which function might have the error.

Answer (score 0):

i do something similar but in the layout i set the onClick value to the same function for each button and then have a function like below. All 10 buttons  hit this function,maybe you can try this approach

```
    public void onButtonClick( View v )
    {
        Button but = (Button) findViewById( v.getId() );
        String input = but.getText().toString();
```